# Salesforce SOAP API gives Other Apex API Invalid Password using PHP

Tags: soap-api, login-errors, grant-login-access, grant-login

as the title says my account returns this error whenever i try to access it using the SOAP API, my account is development account i have encountered this before and just created a new account but if this is a recurring issue, I would like to know the way to fix this. Also all the credentials are correct and i can login to my https://ap1.salesforce.com account. also I have tried resetting the password and still the same error occurred. any idea on why this is happening?

Exception INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.

Last Request:

POST /services/Soap/c/27.0 HTTP/1.1 Host: login.salesforce.com Connection: Keep-Alive User-Agent: salesforce-toolkit-php/27.0 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 SOAPAction: "" Content-Length: 343

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely something wrong with your username and password.Please note you need security token appended to password like password+token to access salesforce unless your IP address is in network access .

Comment: i changed them now and got it to connect to SOAP again, but why did it prompt that before i changed my password and token?

Comment: sorry i did not get you but invalid password implies something wrong in username and password or security token .Also note each time you change password security token gets changed

Comment: sorry if I didn't made my self clear enough, I was working with the same credentials a few days ago until recently I wasn't able to connect to the SOAP api anymore thus prompting me to check for errors and  I found out the Exception INVALID_LOGIN error. any reason for my account to just automatically turn to this?

Comment: One reason i could think of is password would have expired.Other could be you reset security token or password and forget.It's manual activity .

Comment: is there a way to prevent password expiration?

Comment: Yes ...Google this and i am sure there is a setting to set password never expires

Comment: You can change the password settings in Setup > Security Controls > Password Settings. There is an option for "never expires." Note that if you were *not* using a security token, your IP address may have changed, which would cause logins that were working to suddenly stop.